# Dialog Popup not getting closed in Outlook Desktop, IE and Edge (Outlook Web Add in)

Tags: angular, office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are using Office Dialog API for our Outlook Web Add-in.

- The dialog popup redirects to the local page
- It further redirects to the https://login.microsoftonline.com for
  authentication if not logged in.
- After a successful login, the Dialog is redirected to the local home
  page again and then Dialog closed using **messageParent** function.

We are using **angular-oauth2-oidc** for authentication with Identity Server.

**ref**: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

**Scenarios:**

**1) Chrome**: The whole flow is working as expected.

**2) IE, Edge, and Outlook Desktop:**

- The Dialog popup opens.
- Redirects to https://localhost:44305.
- Redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com.
- After successful login, redirects to https://localhost:44305.
- **Dialog popup did not close.**

**Screenshot of console:**

[image: I found the following errors in IE console]

Comment: Do you see any error messages on your console log in case of IE and Edge? Also could you please share your Outlook Desktop build number?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, Hey, I have attached screenshot of console.

Comment: Does this work on other browsers, like Firefox/Safari? Do you load office js in your localhost page? Also, could you try hosting the application on a shared location(not localhost) and try and let us know the results? For lcoalhost case, does message parent work?